# Pandas MultiIndex with some varying numbers of levels

Tags: pandas, multi-index

Is it possible for a pandas multiIndex to have varying numbers of levels? For example, if you were working with indices `A1, A2, and B`, so that `A` has sublevels `1` and `2`, but `B` has no sublevels? If so, how do you do it?

For example, could you produce a dataframe that looked like this:

```
A               B
1       2   
val1    val2    val3
```

The reason that I'm hoping to avoid adding a sublevel to `B` is that I'm going to use this dataframe to create a JSON object that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        A: {
            1: val1,
            2: val2
        },
        B: val3
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Can you try to show what your desired dataframe would look like

Comment: You may be able to do this with [.reindex()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#data-alignment-and-using-reindex)

Answer (score 0):

MultiIndex doesn't support this kind of behavior, but what you could do is rearrange the DataFrame to look like this:

```
>>> d = {'A': {1: 'val1', 2: 'val2'}, 'B': 'val3'}
>>> pd.DataFrame(d)
    A    B
1  val1 val3
2  val2 val3
```

This way A[1] still points to val1 and A[2] still points to val2, but the only complication would be that you have to treat B as a Series.